# Combinations and Permutations involving a cuboid

Tags: combinatorics

Given a cuboid with opposite vertices P(0,0,0) and Q(2,3,5), I'd like to
find the other six vertices of the box.

[cuboid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nU6aP.png)

A diagram of the rectangular box reveals the answer [2, 0, 0], [0, 3, 0],
[2, 3, 0], [0, 0, 5], [2, 0, 5], and [0, 3, 5]

A computer program also reveals the answer:
[vertices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgp4A.png)

A Cartesian product of the two sets, L1 and L2 (written L1 × L2) is the set of
all ordered pairs that have a member of L1 as the first entry and a member of B as the second entry.  For example,

[Cartesian product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGLbi.png)

The [] symbol is a selection operator which is used to select each component from the aggregate object and the ~ symbol applies the operation to each element in the list.  In the last line of the routine the $ forms and expression sequence for the 2 lists, note that 2 raised to the power 3 (number of elements in each list) equals 8, the total number of vertices.  I don't understand how the routine calculates the 8 vertices coordinates from the cartesian product.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: [You mean "cuboid"?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3P1K0.png)

Comment: spelling error cuboid not cuboic

Comment: For spelling mistakes, you have a little `edit` button underneath your post.

Comment: Thanks, did I put this post in the right place?  Does Mathematics have a place to post questions about pseudocode?